# Throwing EmptyTreeException is not working

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm currently working on a project where I have to make a binary search tree and I'm having a little problem implementing my getRootData method

I've already tried importing different things or trying to find an implemented method but I haven't found any luck.

```
public T getRootData() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyTreeException();
    else
        return root.getData();
}
```

Am I supposed to write a class for EmptyTreeExcpetion or is there something else I need to do.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem/question is.

Comment: @lealceldeiro my IDE keeps telling me " cannot resolve symbol 'EmptyTreeException' "

Comment: @PaulAnthonyMorillo have you written `EmptyTreeException` class ?

Comment: @ZainArshad no i have not, I was wondering if that is what I am supposed to do

Comment: `getRootData()` is not a class, it's a method. Hence it is part of a class. And because it returns `T`, I'm guessing that the class it is part of is a generic class. If you are only using the standard JDK classes along with classes that you wrote, then there is no `EmptyTreeException` class in the JDK, which means you have to write it. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Abra no im not sure how to write the EmptyTreeException, I wasn't sure if it was like the other exceptions that are default in the jdk. I have a textbook that just used EmptyTreeException but they didnt have any implementations of it

Comment: @PaulAnthonyMorillo you can test my answer if it helps or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first you have to write a `EmptyTreeException` class as there is no such built-in class for this

```
public class EmptyTreeException extends RuntimeException
{   
    public EmptyListException()
    {
        super ("Tree is Empty");
    }
}
```

Now, you have to change your `getRootData()` like this:

```
public T getRootData() throws EmptyTreeException
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyTreeException();
    else
        return root.getData();
}
```

**Edit:** You don't have to change your `getRootData()`, as mentioned by fellow SO's users that `EunTimeException` is an "unchecked exception" so no need to do this `throws EmptyTreeException` after method header.

Comment: _Now, you have to change your `getRootData()` like this_  No he doesn't, because your implementation makes `EmptyTreeException` an **unchecked exception**, which seems logical since in the OP's code, method `getRootData()` does not declare that it throws `EmptyTreeException`.

Comment: @Abra you are right ... I just did what I used to do for years ... hahaaI understood it now :)

Comment: _wouldn't it give any error ?_  There's one way to find out ;-)

Comment: @lealceldeiro can you enlighten me about this being "nota good idea"..? any help is appreciated

Comment: Interesting, @lealceldeiro, a lot of people I come across tend to think _checked_ exceptions should be avoided at all costs. Regardless, you should extend the exception that makes sense. In this case, I don't see the benefit in making `EmptyTreeException` a checked exception—it's similar to `NoSuchElementException`, which is unchecked. In other words, if the tree is empty it's probably a _programming error_ rather than a _recoverable error_ caused by something outside the developers control.

Comment: I agree with @Slaw and personally try to use unchecked exceptions in preference to checked ones, but I defer to Josh Bloch's book _Effective Java, Third Edition_, namely item 70: _Use checked exceptions for recoverable conditions and runtime exceptions for programming errors_.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @PaulAnthonyMorillo,

There is not the class exception EmptyTreeException on any JDK. Then we need to create a class that extends Exception or RuntimeException to throw it.

We can verify if there is a class on java search on javadoc. Like [javadoc on jdk11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html)

I hope I have helped,

Comment: _There is not the class exception EmptyTreeException on jdk 11._  Please enlighten me because I didn't see any mention of JDK version being used in the original question. In any case, there has **never** been a `EmptyTreeException` in any JDK version.

Comment: Hi @Abra, I only check Exception on jdk11. I think it would be enough. But I did not  know and did not check in others jdks. I will fix the answer. Thanks by feedback :)